# Correcting HTML layout

Tags: html, css

I am working on creating a sample html page for a friend's project. I have created the initial layout, but I am having trouble in getting the layout right.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bymo07e/)

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Online Store</title>

    <style>
    header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
   }

    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #111;
}

    li {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
    li a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

    fieldset {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
        </style>
      </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Company Heading</h1>
        </header>
        <fieldset id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <article id="main-content">
            <h3>Welcome to our collections</h3>
            <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous
                city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13
                million inhabitants.</p>
        </article>

        <footer>Copyright under process © CompanyName 2012-2020.</footer>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I have two problems:

1. The navigation bar and whole body width going beyond visible screen.
2. I want to fix the page height, somehow it is stuck to the content. I want to make it fill the browser height.

I am doing a web project after a gap of 5 years, so please bear with my silly mistakes. Thanks in advance.

**Updated**: Adding more problem to this thread.
I have updated my layout to show more components. Here is my current html:
https://jsfiddle.net/8bzjv8e0/

Current objectives:
1. Fixing the menu bar to have black theme and proper spacing and alignment.
2. Divide main content area to create area for left navigation bar and main content area.

Here is my code:

```
 <body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Our Collection</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Menu3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Menu4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container" id="body-layout">
            <div id="left-nav-bar" class="left-nav">left nav contents</div>

            <div id="content" class="right-content">main content area</div>

        </div>

        <footer>Copyright under process © Company Name 2017-2020.</footer>
    </div>

</body>

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
    blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn,
    em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas,
    details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav,
    output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
    background: #F5F4EF;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

article {
    flex: 1;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color:  #F5F4EF;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav {
 text-align: left;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

nav a {
    color: #F5F4EF;
}

/* Headings */
h1 {
    font-size: 1.651em
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.571em
} /* 22px */
h3 {
    font-size: 1.429em
} /* 20px */
h4 {
    font-size: 1.286em
} /* 18px */
h5 {
    font-size: 1.143em
} /* 16px */
h6 {
    font-size: 1em
} /* 14px */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
    color: #F5F4EF;
}

.left-nav {
    background-color: Red;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
}

.right-content {
    background-color: Aqua;
    margin-left: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you would could make the footer position absolute to the bottom or you could make the `.container` `display: flex;` like I did in the examples below. You could reach for something like bootstrap but then again, the learning curve for it might be more then you wish for depending on your relation to frontend development?

as you have a container wrapping the content you could/should apply your styles to that. Even if you apply styles to the body it wont affect the div inside unless the content takes up the full page.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bymo07e/2/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

article {
  flex: 1;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #111;
}

li {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Company Heading</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article id="main-content">
    <h3>Welcome to our collections</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  </article>

  <footer>Copyright under process © CompanyName 2012-2020.</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dejan, I missed your post before. This is very resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vh (viewport height), and vw (viewport width) for making full screen(height/width) pages. Also do not forget to reset all element for better solution. Because browser's have it's own default values and you need to reset that to make sure your page seems same in different browsers.

```
<style>
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
</style>
```

And also why don't you use something like bootstrap or materialize css? They're helpful and easy to use.

Comment: Why use bootstrap for something simple like this?

Comment: Thanks. I am able to get the width resolved. What should I do for height problem? I would also like to know if are any modern solutions to creating templates. I am not in touch with latest web technologies.

Comment: It is easy, but bootstrap shouldn't be a go to thing for every project though, it depends on how complex it should be.

Comment: @kromastorm if you want something easy to build with then check out bootstrap as Özgur suggests.

Comment: @kromastorm did you try this?
    body{min-height: 100vh;} 
That makes your body's min height as your screen height.

Comment: okay, the min-height did not work. will keep trying to get this right.

Comment: @kromastorm check my answer, that will solve your problems

Comment: @kromastorm https://jsfiddle.net/6ngn1e1o/ 
but Dejan's method is good too.

Comment: Okay, will see how bootstrap can be used. Meanwhile, I have found out that I had a div container inside my body, that is why the min-height was not working. It is resolved now. Thanks Dejan and Ozgur.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. Personally I would use Flexbox, which is a native CSS solution so you don't need to use an external library.

The approach that you take is largely up to you, and your choice is often based around what feels the most straightforward or most intuitive. Have a read around some examples. There are a number of methods here are https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/ , some of which may feel more intuitive than others, but copy-paste and give them a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do not wish to make my project browser specific. I have had a very troublesome experience with the IE family of browsers in my previous projects.